# Cocos RichElementText mis aligned inside RichText if enableRetina true on mobile browser

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

I am using Cocos2d-x 3.13.1, on game start I am calling `cc.view.enableRetina(true)`. But, due to this, `ccui.RichElementText` inside `ccui.RichText` is mis-aligned.

misaligned screenshot:

[image: mis-aligned screenshot]

If I set `cc.view.enableRetina(false)`, cocos renders blurred fonts.

Blurred fonts screenshot:

[image: Blurred fonts screenshot]

This is happening only if I compile cocos for web and not reproducible if compiled for Android.

Any solution for this?